# Calculating trigonometric integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need some help to solve this integral:

$$\int_0^1 dy\int_0^{1-y} \cos \left(\frac{x-y}{x+y} \right) \mathrm dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: Is this part of another problem, like computing a double integral?

Comment: Have you tried any substitutions?

Comment: Doesn't look good : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28%28x-a%29%2F%28x%2Ba%29%29

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. The integral is
$$
\iint_T\cos \Bigl(\frac{x-y}{x+y} \Bigr) \mathrm dx.
$$
Now there is a quite obvious change of variable that will simplify the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u=\frac{x-y}{x+y}=1-\frac{2y}{x+y}$. Inverting,

$$\frac{2y}{x+y}=1-u\\
\implies x+y=\frac{2y}{1-u}\\
\implies x=\frac{2y}{1-u}-y.$$

Then the differential is $dx=\frac{2y}{(1-u)^2}du$. The double integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{-1}^{1-2y}\frac{2y}{(1-u)^2}\cos{u}\,du.$$

Changing the order of integration then makes this integral much more tractable.