# Solving $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-y} \sin\frac{x-y}{x+y}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How would I go about solving the following double integral?

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-y} \sin\frac{x-y}{x+y}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$

I am absolutely clueless on what to do with that sine.

Comment: Have you tried to do a $u=x-y$, $v=x+y$ substitution (haven't tried myself, just a question)?

Comment: I tried it, I'm going to try it again to see what happens.

Comment: @Martigan it feels like I'm going in a loop, doesn't look like it's going to be helpful.

Comment: maybe related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787926/calculating-trigonometric-integral  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313378/integral-int-01-int-01-y-cos-left-fracx-yxy-rightdxdy  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452462/how-to-get-the-interval-after-change-of-variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our integral is the integral of $\sin\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ over the triangle with vertices in the origin, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. By rotating this region $45^\circ$ clockwise around the origin, i.e. by setting $u=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}},v=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}$, we get:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-u}^{u}\sin\frac{v}{u}\,dv\,du=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}u\int_{-1}^{1}\sin t\,dt\,du = 0.$$

Comment: That was pretty challenging.... Thanks!