# How to get the interval after change of variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

> Let $D$ be the region bounded by $x+y = 1$, $x= 0$, $y = 0$. Use the result of [Exercise 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4LAz.png) to show that $$\iint_D\cos\bigg(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\bigg)~dx~dy = \frac{\sin 1}{2} $$
>   and graph $D$ on an $xy$ plane and a $uv$ plane, with $u = x-y$ and $v = x+y$.

I got the Jacobian determinant is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, but how do I get the limits of integration for $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Exercise 19${}$?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8ODGDJ7.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For convenience, let's write your change of variable as:
$$x=\frac{u+v}{2},\qquad y=\frac{v-u}{2} \tag{1}$$

---

The most obvious thing to do when trying to find the region $D^*$ in the $uv$-plane corresponding to region $D$ is to *sketch the region of integration*:

[image]

By substitution of equations $(1)$, we notice that the image lines of $y=0$, $x=0$ and $y=1-x$ in the $uv$-plane is $v=u$, $v=-u$ and $v=1$ respectively, as shown below:
$$y=0 \implies \frac{v-u}{2}=0 \implies u=v$$
$$x=0 \implies \frac{u+v}{2}=0 \implies u=-v$$
$$y=1-x \implies \frac{v-u}{2}=1-\frac{u+v}{2}\implies v-u=2-u-v \implies v=1$$

---

Let's now sketch the new region $D^*$:

[image]

Notice that it is more convenient to describe $D^*$ as a [type II plane region](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/m408d/CurrentWeb/LM15-3-2.php):
$$D^*=\{(u,v)\mid 0\leq v \leq 1, -v\leq u \leq v\}$$
Therefore, the integral becomes:
$$\iint_D \cos\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)~dA=\iint_{D^*} \cos(u/v)\cdot \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|~du~dv=\int_0^1 \int_{-v}^v \frac{\cos(u/v)}{2}~du~dv=\frac{\sin(1)}{2}$$
The last line is easily verifiable, and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

> Let $D$ be the region bounded by $x+y = 1$, $x= 0$, $y = 0$.  with $u = x-y$ and $v = x+y$.

$D$ is $\mathop\triangle\limits_{x,y}(0,0)(0,1)(1,0)$, and the transformation is a rotation and scale shift to $D^*$ which is $\mathop\triangle\limits_{u,v}(0{-}0,0{+}0)(0{-}1,0{+}1)(1{-}0,1{+}0)$.

Alternatively:

As $x=(u+v)/2, y=(v-u)/2$ , then $~D=\{(x,y): x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x+y\leq 1\}\\D^\ast{=\{(u,v): u{+}v\geq 0, v{-}u\geq 0, (u{+}v){+}(v{-}u)\leq 2\} \\= \{(u,v): {0\leq v\leq 1, -v\leq u\leq v}\}}$

Comment: I assume that the scale shift is because of the Jacobian. Could you explain how you saw it was also a rotation by inspection?

Comment: Because the transformation of the position vectors is: $\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$, and from experience that transformation matrix has the familiar form of $\sqrt 2\;\begin{bmatrix} \cos (\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4) \\ \sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4) \end{bmatrix}$. @JessicaK